# Java Quick Sort Implementation (Code fix)

Tags: java, quicksort

I have written my version of the Quick Sort in Java but I'm running into a bit of a problem while calling the second recursion. This is my code:

```
public static int[] quickSort(int[] array, int start, int end) {
    int pIndex;
    if (start < end) {
        int left = start;
        int right = end - 1;
        int pivot = array[end];

        //Start the partitioning

        while (left < right) {
            if (array[left] > pivot && array[right] < pivot) {
                int temp = array[left];
                array[left] = array[right];
                array[right] = temp;
                left++;
                right--;
            } else if (array[left] > pivot)
                right--;
            else
                left++;
        }

        if (array[end] < array[left]) {
            int temp = array[left];
            array[left] = array[end];
            array[end] = temp;
            pIndex = left;
        } else
        pIndex = end;
        //End partitioning            

        quickSort(array, 0, pIndex - 1);
        quickSort(array, pIndex + 1, array.length - 1);
    }
    return array;
}
```

The parameter start will be the index of the first element in the array and end will be the index of the last one and I am picking the last element as the pivot.

The issue I am running into is at **quickSort(array, pIndex + 1, array.length - 1);**

The array.length-1 causes this to go on infinitely since it is with reference to the original array. Is there any way for me to fix this without having to pass a new array to the function everytime?

I did try to create a global variable to store the new lengths but I wasn't able to do it quite right.

Thanks in advance.

I'm sorry if the code is not a very nice implementation of the Sort. I wanted to write one from scratch on my own but turns out I ran into problems anyway.

Comment: Why are you using 0 and length - 1 and not start and end?

Comment: kill me already! start and end was an instant fix. I can't believe I messed up so badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way of using recursion in QuickSort is to use `start`, `pivot` and `end`.

You appear to be using inclusive-end indexing; then you will want to recurse into

```
quicksort(data, start, pivot - 1)
quicksort(data, pivot + 1, end)
```

The pivot element is already in its final position.

Comment: This fixed it. I feed stupid now. I looked at the code for 3 hours trying to come up with a fix.